# In app purchases with MKStoreKit failing: "Problem in iTunes connect configuration for product: xxx"

Tags: iphone, sdk, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm trying to implement in app purchases in my App using MKStoreKit. I've followed all the steps and I'm getting the error:

Problem in iTunes connect configuration for product:

I've recreated the provisioning profiles, checked the product id is the same as in itunes connect, sent and rejected a binary, trying to delete everything and set it up again and nothing is working.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It didn't work in my case cause the phone was jailbroken. After restoring it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a late reply, but somehow I could not find the answer to this problem elsewhere so I decided to post my experience in hopes it might help other frustrated people with this issue.

I have recently added an In-App purchase to my Free app and I faced the same problem during the testing phase and also once it was launched on App Store.

The answer is Patience. For some odd reason, after doing everything correctly, you need to wait for around a day before your product is recognized. So once you finish your Manage In-App product ID, you will only see it working the following day - so don't delete and recreate it again - just wait.

Furthermore, after submitting your app for approval with the first In-App product, even when your app is approved and available in the App Store, the In-App might not work at first and you will feel you did something wrong. Wait another day or so, and magically, it will start to work.

Comment: the reason you have to wait has to do with Apple's server refresh cycle. It can take a few hours to a day for changes you've made to propogate across all of Apple's servers.

Answer (score 1):

my ipad was jailbroken. it was given this "Problem in iTunes connect configuration for product: xxx" i changed my ipad with regular(no jailbrek) ipad and it's working now.