# Resolving invalid product id issue with in-app purchases?

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, subscriptions

This is a follow-up question to "[In app purchases with MKStoreKit failing: “Problem in iTunes connect configuration for product: xxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868728/in-app-purchases-with-mkstorekit-failing-problem-in-itunes-connect-configurati)"

I am having a similar issue and have tried to do both with and without MKStoreKit and get a similar message.

**Check-list**

With thanks to: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/

*Have you enabled In-App Purchases for your App ID?*

YES

*Have you checked Cleared for Sale for your product?*

YES

*Have you submitted (and optionally rejected) your application binary?*

YES

*Does your project’s .plist Bundle ID match your App ID?*

YES

*Have you generated and installed a new provisioning profile for the new App ID?*

YES

*Have you configured your project to code sign using this new provisioning profile?*

YES

*Are you building for iPhone OS 3.0 or above?*

YES. iOS4.2 and up.

*Are you using the full product ID when when making an SKProductRequest?*

YES. Also just the product ID itself without the reverse domain

*Have you waited several hours since adding your product to iTunes Connect?*

YES. It says "Waiting for review" and has done for the past 4-5 days

*Are your bank details active on iTunes Connect?*

NO. It is a client project and am only testing to see if it is working.  Do I need bank details to test it?

EDIT: I have changed this now. But I do not see why I need to do this just to test sandboxing.

*Have you tried deleting the app from your device and reinstalling?*

YES

*Is your device jailbroken?*

NO

---

**App notation is correct**

Some examples I have seen use this notation:
com.domain.APP_ID.PRODUCT_TO_BUY

But others use
com.domain.PRODUCT_TO_BUY

Which is right?

In my code I have attempted using the full notation and just the product ID itself but still get the same problem of "Invalid product id".

**Developer rejected**

App Bundle (Release) is on iTunes Connect and I have "developer rejected" the bundle.

Picture:
[image: App developer rejected]

**Waiting for review?**

In my in-app purchases I have the 1 product, an auto-renewable subscription.  It is cleared for sale; it is however "Waiting for review" and is not green-lit.

Picture:

[image: waiting for review]

I created this almost 4-5 days ago and its still flagged as "Waiting for review"??

I am wondering if my app has been "developer rejected" whether this has an impact on "Waiting for review" on an auto-renewable subscription?

I have not changed anything in this item.

According to the various articles I have to wait 24-48 hours before I can use it?

But do I need to wait for this to be accepted or green-lit before I can use it in my testing?

**Bank details**

I have not filled in any bank details because this is an app for a client -- Do I need to fill in bank details before I can continue testing it?

According to these docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html  bank details are required?

**Do I need to be logged into iTunes on my device under a test account before running the app?**

I am wondering if someone can clarify these issues?  Maybe its just as simple as waiting for the in-app purchase to be "green lit", or perhaps I've missed a step?

Note: This happens regardless of whether I use MKStoreKit or use the code that follows.

Thanks.

My code (this is the non MKStoreKit version)

```
#define kMySubscriptionFeature @"uk.co.samplewebsite.myappproject.sub1"

    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.title = @"Manage Subscriptions";


    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
    {
        // Display a store to the user.

        //[MKStoreManager sharedManager];
        //NSLog(@"purhcasable = %@", [[MKStoreManager sharedManager] purchasableObjectsDescription] );
        [self requestProUpgradeProductData];

    }
    else
    {
        // Warn the user that purchases are disabled.
        NSString *message = @"In-app purchases are disabled. Please review your settings";
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];
    } // end if
}


#pragma mark - StoreKit Delegate

- (void) requestProductData
{
    SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: [NSSet setWithObject:kMySubscriptionFeature]];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSArray *myProduct = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:response.products];

    for(SKProduct *item in myProduct)
    {

        NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , item.localizedTitle);
        NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , item.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , item.price);
        NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , item.productIdentifier);
    }


    for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem in iTunes connect configuration for product: %@" , invalidProductId);
    }


    [myProduct release];

    // populate UI
    [request autorelease];
}
```

Edit:

As a failsafe, I've added bank details just in case, but I don't see why this would cause an issue.

I've also made sure I uploaded and rejected the app release bundle and not the adhoc one; though I do not know if this makes any difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I've done it now.  I'm going to run some tests just to make sure.

This is not going to be accepted just yet; I am running some tests with different storekit frameworks.

My output:

```
2011-10-27 15:17:49.297 My Simple App[7376:707] productsRequest
2011-10-27 15:17:49.298 My Simple App[7376:707] Product title: Simple subscription
2011-10-27 15:17:49.299 My Simple App[7376:707] Product description: Subscribe and get the latest content to your iPhone or iPod Touch device
2011-10-27 15:17:49.299 My Simple App[7376:707] Product price: 2.99
2011-10-27 15:17:49.300 My Simple App[7376:707] Product id: sub1
```

Here's what I did.

1. I added my bank details.  I still do not think this has anything to do with it though.
2. Note. The app's in-app purchase is still "Waiting for review" and I got the above output.
3. I replaced:

   `#define kMySubscriptionFeature @"uk.co.somesite.someapp.sub1"`

with:

```
#define kMySubscriptionFeature @"sub1"
```

I am going to run some tests with MKStoreKit and with other frameworks to see if it is okay.

The code I used is below, edited for security reasons:

.h file

```
//  ManageSubscriptionsVC.h
//  This doesn't have visual output, just NSLog at the moment
//  This doesn't use MKStoreKit yet

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "StoreKit/StoreKit.h"

#define kMySubscriptionFeature @"sub1"

/*
 Shared Secret
 
 A shared secret is a unique code that you should use when you make the 
 call to our servers for your In-App Purchase receipts. 
 Without a shared secret, you will not be able to test auto-renewable 
 In-App Purchase subscriptions in the sandbox mode. 
 
 Also note that you will not be able to make them available 
 on the App Store.
 
 Note: Regardless of what app they are associated with, 
 all of your auto-renewable subscriptions will use this 
 same shared secret.
 */
#define sharedSecret @"PUTSHAREDSECRETHERE"


@interface ManageSubscriptionsVC : UIViewController
<SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver>
{
    SKProduct *proUpgradeProduct;
    SKProductsRequest *productsRequest;
}

- (void)requestProUpgradeProductData;

@end
```

.m file

```
//
//  ManageSubscriptionsVC.m

#import "ManageSubscriptionsVC.h"

@implementation ManageSubscriptionsVC

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.title = @"Manage Subscriptions";
    
    
    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
    {
        // Display a store to the user.
        
        //[MKStoreManager sharedManager];
        //NSLog(@"purhcasable = %@", [[MKStoreManager sharedManager] purchasableObjectsDescription] );
        [self requestProUpgradeProductData];
        
    }
    else
    {
        // Warn the user that purchases are disabled.
        NSString *message = @"In-app purchases are disabled. Please review your settings";
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];
    } // end if
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - StoreKit Delegate

- (void) requestProductData
{
    NSLog(@"requestProductData");
    SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: [NSSet setWithObject:kMySubscriptionFeature]];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"productsRequest");
    
    NSArray *myProduct = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:response.products];
    
    for(SKProduct *item in myProduct)
    {
        
        NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , item.localizedTitle);
        NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , item.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , item.price);
        NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , item.productIdentifier);
        
        
    }

    /*
    for(NSString *invalidProduct in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
        NSLog(@"Problem in iTunes connect configuration for product: %@", invalidProduct);
    */
    
    for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem in iTunes connect configuration for product: %@" , invalidProductId);
    }
    
    
    [myProduct release];
    
    // populate UI
    [request autorelease];
}

#pragma mark - PaymentQueue

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue removedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
}

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
{
}

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
}

-(void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
}

#pragma mark - Other


- (void)requestProUpgradeProductData
{
    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:kMySubscriptionFeature];
    productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];
    
    // we will release the request object in the delegate callback
}





@end
```

Answer (score 11):

After 2 days of waiting, new app ids, profiles, etc. this fixed it for me..

Why do the docs say to use the full com.iap.isrubbish syntax?

Thanks for your help

> I replaced:
>
> ## define kMySubscriptionFeature @"uk.co.somesite.someapp.sub1"
>
> with:
>
> ## define kMySubscriptionFeature @"sub1"

Comment: WOW... I spent 1 whole week searching for a mistake. I deleted 2 bundles, created new ones, did a whole lot of research just to find this. And it worked... I just want to hug you both. :D

Comment: I've gotten some sales while using the full id. But I'm still getting invalid product id errors for some users. Will changing this at 2016 work?

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that I swapped the product ID and the reference name when I created the in app purchase, so in my case I was using the wrong string to try and find the Product... Hard to spot.

Answer (score 1):

I was testing the newest version of my existing, fully-functioning app with in app-purchase to ensure the functionality was still working as expected, when I began to seeing the problems in iTunes connect message. My problem was (I forgot) that MKStoreKit stored the fact of the purchase on my various devices' keychain, so even though I was using a new user account, my keychain was registering the device as already purchased.
[self removeAllKeychainData] from within MKStoreManager fixed the trouble.
Hope this saves someone some frustration.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was, I had logged in on device using real apple id. Then signed out ( Iphone-> Settings -> App Store -> My ID-> Sign Out)
Then deployed again, and hurray it worked.

Thanks everyone on web.