# In app purchase - Ionic Framework

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am trying to implement in app purchase using Ionic Framework. I followed https://devdactic.com/ionic-in-app-purchase-ios/ - to implement in app purchase. I also created a record for in app purchase in itunesConnect, but I am getting below error when I try to fetch the records :

> products request received response
>
> invalid product with id com.abc.def.bronzee

I am not sure what's my mistake here while implementation. I also tried to add bank details in Agreements, tax and banking section it's showing Request Contracts block, in which  when I click on Request button it is showing to add new Legal entity and my company details and address. Any help with respect to this issue is much appreciated. Thanks.. Please let me know if I have missed to add something in my questions.

Comment: Check your product identifier in xcode with itunesconnect. Are both are same?

Comment: Yes, I think its Bundle Identifier, in Xcode and in itunesconnect both are same.. But the in-app-purchase I've created in itunesconnect have the status as Ready to Submit, is that what it is effecting?

Comment: No.Its not at all about ready to submit status.

Comment: @Shivam Tripathi thank you for replying. What could be the reason can you please look into this a little bit more I am unable to understand what's wrong with the error I am getting and didn't find the relevant reference too.. Thanks

Comment: Check out these things : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915327/resolving-invalid-product-id-issue-with-in-app-purchases